# Quicker cleaning and removal of variable levels

Tags: r

Embarrassingly when I am conducting data cleaning and removal levels of variables which are coded for non-response, I always go through a laborious process on each variable so I wondered if there are quicker ways to do this. I'm sure there are more efficient ways.

E.g in a survey dataset where the numeric value 66 means 'Not applicable', 77 means 'Don't know', 99 means 'Refusal', I usually do as follows:

```
euro$eduyrs[euro$eduyrs==77] <- NA
euro$eduyrs[euro$eduyrs==88] <- NA
euro$eduyrs[euro$eduyrs==99] <- NA
```

This is a clunky and flawed approach, so I wanted to ask is there a quicker way to exclude all these values for all variables?

Comment: Why not use `%in%` in one step i.e. `euro$eduyrs[euro$eduyrs %in% c(77, 88, 99)] <- NA`

Comment: Consider posting on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if the code is working.

Comment: thanks @akrun a good suggestion - I wonder if I could do this for several variables at once? There is only one variable in my dataset where this would mess up which is actual age (since respondents can validly be 77, 88 or 99)

Comment: You can use `lapply` i.e. `df1[cols] <- lapply(df1[cols], function(x) replace(x, x %in% c(77, 88, 99), NA))`